# Connect to Azure Synapse from Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

We have users where they want to connect to Azure Synapse from Power BI. We ensure that they have the proper permission to access Synapse tables.

They can connect to Synapse tables when using their own internet. However, when they are connecting from the office*(where I assume they are connecting thru VPN)*, they have connection issue as shown below.

[image]

Does somebody encountered this and know how to resolve the issue?
I was looking in the web but could not find the solution.

Thank you.

Below are the items that we did to resolve the issue:

- Added the reader permission to Azure Synapse and Storage account.
- Whitelisted IP address of the user in Azure Synapse.

Comment: make sure when you connect through your office VPN you are whitelisting that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> They can connect to Synapse tables when using their own internet. However, when they are connecting from the office*(where I assume they are connecting thru VPN)*, they have connection issue as shown below.

The office has a firewall blocking outbound port 1433.  Talk to your network people.